# How to hide console window from Windows Gtk C programs compiled with cl

Tags: c, windows, gtk3, cl, compileoptions

Due to unstable and unreliable mingw / MSYS2 behaviours on Windows 11 (x86_64), I have decided to use the Windows-native `cl` compiler bundled with Visual Studio to compile Gtk 3 programs written in C.  I am using Gtk 3 built with the [gvsbuild](https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild) script.  My Gtk 3 test program compiles successfully with the `cl` compiler, using a compiler [command-file](https://web.archive.org/web/20220419135908/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/at-specify-a-compiler-response-file?view=msvc-170) / response-file for the compile and linker options, but when I run the compiled Gtk 3 program, I get a console window behind it.

[image: Image of Gtk test program with console behind it]

I have searched tirelessly on StackOverflow as well as the rest of the internet and have not found a solution that addresses my `cl`-specific situation.

I have tried using `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` which causes a compiler error because the compiler can't find WinMain hidden by Gtk.  I have tried `/D"subsystem,windows"`, `/Dmwindows` as well as `/Dsubsystem=gui` with and without the `-` in front, but none solve the issue.

I have also tried this bit of code, which causes a huge amount of errors because the compiler can't find Windows-specific code hidden by Gtk:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
AllocConsole();
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
#endif
```

Here is the test program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication * app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget * window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello internet from Gtk Windows!");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  GtkApplication * app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

I've elected not to post the compiler command-file contents as it's quite lengthy.

For those who may answer "Just use mingw, MSYS2, cygwin, etc" I'd rather stay with a `cl`-specific solution please.

Is there a `cl`-specific option for suppressing the console window when compiling and running C Gtk 3 programs on Windows?

---

**A big thanks to Tony Lee** for the recommendation!  This code is working properly after specifying `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` in the linker options:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication * app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget * window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello internet from Gtk Windows!");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

#ifdef _WIN32
int WinMain (void * hInstance, void * hPrevInstance, char ** argv, int nCmdShow)
#else
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
#endif
{
  GtkApplication * app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

It should be noted that I had to put a zero for the `argc` value in `g_application_run()`, so that's another (minor) issue I'll have to figure out later, but if your Gtk program doesn't need to process command-line arguments, it's fine.

Comment: Did you try defining `WinMain(HINSTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, char *, int) ` when using `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` instead of `main`?

Comment: @TonyLee Thanks for that. :-)  Tried that right now and it causes syntax errors, presumably because it doesn't recognize the Windows-centric identifiers.  Added `#include <windows.h>` which caused more errors.  Also would like to keep the code as cross-platform as possible.

Comment: I'd just use `void*` instead of `HINSTANCE *` and not include windows.h and maybe you'll have to make up parameter names - my only other concern is C vs Pascal Calling convention - I'm pretty sure it'll be C so it'll work.  I wish I could test but I don't have access to a VS at the moment.  The MS documentation is inconsistent - the subsystem doc says HINSTANCE * and the WinMain entry point say just HINSTANCE.

Comment: @TonyLee I tried `int WinMain (void * hInstance, void * hPrevInstance, char ** pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` and also had to rework `g_application_run()` but now it runs, and without the console.  Thanks!  Go ahead and make this an answer and I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS 2022 help on `/SUBSYSTEM` under `Windows` says to use it when:

> The application doesn't require a console, probably because it creates
> its own windows for interaction with the user.

Which is exactly what's required here - There's a Raymon Chen article called "WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point" so when the OP found it undefined, it just needed to be declared instead of `main`.  It documents the `WinMain` prototype as:

`WinMain(HINSTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, char *, int)`

However, MS documents the `WinMain` prototype without the `*` on `HINSTANCE` in an article called "WinMain: The Application Entry Point" as

`int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);`

You could include `Windows.h` but it doesn't appear there's a requirement to use `hInstance` and `hPrevInstance` so `void *` should work as a substitute.